# How to add a column if line contains string?

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, columns

If I have a tab-delimited file containing the following lines:

```
Sample1-Baboon  1  2  3  4
Sample2-Human   1  2  3  4
Sample3-Human   1  2  3  4
Sample4-Baboon  1  2  3  4
```

How can I add a new column at the end of the line for those lines which contain the string `'Baboon'` ?

Comment: `awk -v OFS='\t' '/Baboon/{$(NF+1)=5}1'`

Comment: what do you want in the new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is named `baboon.txt`:
`sed '/Baboon/ s/$/ Baboon/' baboon.txt`

To write the changes to file use the `-i` option.

`sed -i '/Baboon/ s/$/ Baboon/' baboon.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/Baboon/ s/$/\t5/' your_file
```

This will search `your_file` for the lines containing `Baboon` and replace the last character on those lines with a `tab character` followed by a `5`.  The `-i` will write the changes to the file `in-place`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/Baboon/s/$/\t5/' -cx file
```

1. `g` global regex
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close